# Dart manual translation text problem with double letter key's value never shows

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently facing this problem with flutter (dart):

```
var data = {
 "U": "উ",
 "UU": "ঊ",
}
```

UU's value never get printed it print U's value twice and this is the code I'm using on `TextField` `onchange(val)` method:

```
onChanged: (val){
   editingController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: editingController.text.length));
   setState(() {
     offset = editingController.selection.extentOffset;
     text = editingController.text;
     translated = [];
     myArr = val.split('');

   if(value == " " || value.contains('\n') || value.contains('\b')){
     text = "";
   }else{
     myArr.forEach((element) {
       if(data.containsKey(element)) {

           translated.add(data[element]);

        }
     });

     print(translated.toList().join(''));

   }
    
  })
}
```

```
Input: UU
Output:
[উ, উ] not [ঊ]
```

Comment: Could you please add the output which is printed?

Comment: edited the post see the output

Comment: could you add a print statement that prints val and another which prints myArr as that might help with debugging this issue? I'm not sure yet but believe the split splits it per character which results in the array being [U, U] instead of [UU] which makes the for each run twice and the map gets "U" which is "উ" in the map.

Comment: that's the point, How should I build` myArr`? if you try this TextField with given data you'll understand. @Hady

Comment: Did you try this bro https://pub.dev/packages/bangla_utilities

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Asif but I know that if you split the string by character, it will always just pass 'U' and nothing else. If you want to split it by space then in the `split(' ')` with a space in between. Because the current way the code works from my understanding is that you are splitting the `val` by character so `UU` will be `U` and `U`. So the `data` array will always be asked to look for a key of a single character making it impossible to get a key with more than one character such as `UU`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with an answer with reduce. The idea is that I can actually get repeated value by the following method and append it to the same index of the array (where repeating started) with following code:

```
["U","U"].reduce((element, prev) {
       if(element == prev) {

           print(element+prev);

        }
        return element+prev;
     });
}
```